# Brillouin Peak Localisation - Brillouin Imaging/Spectro-microscopy

Tags: optics, spectroscopy, microscopy

I'm currently looking at ways of identifying the Stokes and anti-Stokes peaks in a Brillouin spectrum in the absence of Rayleigh peaks.

The spectrum sort of looks like the shown below, but lacks the very large ones seen below (the Rayleigh peaks) - so it's only the small ones (Stokes and anti-Stokes) that we're interested in.

[[image: Brillouinn spectrum intensity spectrum,]

Beucase I'm looking at the spectra in terms of CCD pixel numbers instead of frequency, the peak separations, and the widths of the intereference orders, are nonlinear with increasing with pixel number (i.e., the set-up is dispersive).

I am also hoping to account for the detection of small (but not intra-order) spurious features.

I'd appreciate any insights.